# Custom action based on FCM notifications when the app in the background

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm implementing a feature in an android app where I need to preform a series of actions based on notifications received from other users.
When the app is in the foreground I get the notification content in the onMessageReceived() method in the firebase messaging service
But when the app is in the background the android system handle the notification itself.
But I need to be able to get the content of the notification whether my app is in the background or in the foreground.
So I need help to deal with the case when the app is in the background I need to get the notification content on my app so that I can preform my serries of actions based on the notification content.

I can't get my app to act as predicted when it's in the background.

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).